# How to remove XML tags from Unix command line?

Tags: xml, shell, unix, command-line, xml-parsing

I am grepping an XML File, which gives me output like this:

```
<tag>data</tag>
<tag>more data</tag>
...
```

Note, this is a flat file, not an XML tree. I want to remove the XML tags and just display the data in between. I'm doing all this from the command line and was wondering if there is a better way than piping it into awk twice...

```
cat file.xml | awk -F'>' '{print $2}' | awk -F'<' '{print $1}'
```

Ideally, I would like to do this in one command

Comment: *"I am grepping an XML File"* - *"this is a flat file, not an XML tree"* - Now, is the file well-formed XML or not?

Comment: Perhaps I should have been a bit clearer - it is a well formed XML file, but once I've piped it through grep it's no longer an XML tree structure, it's essentially a flat file.

Comment: Ahh, now it makes sense to me. Anyway I've aked because the *clean* version would be to pass this XML file through XSLT, instead of through grep/sed. I'd write an XSLT answer but you seem to have picked your poison. :-)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If your file looks just like that, then `sed` can help you:

```
sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' file.xml
```

Of course [you should not use regular expressions for parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) [because it's hard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/78845).

Comment: @pav1: I wouldn't recommend using [tag:sed] for cleaning up [tag:html], for the reasons highlighted in the linked post!

Comment: @Johnsyweb: Thanks for the heads-up...your suggestion is the best I've tried for stripping tags so I can process words into a most-common list (using tr/sort/sed). I read your links about problem—seems the culprit is mainly nested HTML tags? I'm also reading that parsing is the better solution...to a Bash scripting newbie, how to parse HTML? I'm only finding references to regex solutions. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there any way to preserve/insert line breaks with this? I'm, trying to strip XML tags from a Jenkins API multi-GIT SHA query. When using this command the shas are all stuck together, making it impossible to distinguish between them.

Comment: @BadmintonCat: If your XML doesn't look exactly like that in the question, I really wouldn't recommend using `sed`.

Comment: If you are like me and want to get rid of a SOAP envelope around a base64 content: just add a small dot before the star: 
    sed -e 's/<[^>].*>//g' file.xml

Answer (score 4):

Using awk:

```
awk '{gsub(/<[^>]*>/,"")};1' file.xml
```

Comment: On testing html page, results seem identical to sed (above). Thanks for posting the awk method!

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
grep -Po '<.*?>\K.*?(?=<.*?>)' inputfile
```

Explanation:

Using Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (`-P`) and outputting only the specified matches (`-o`):

- `<.*?>` - Non-greedy match of any characters within angle brackets
- `\K` - Don't include the preceding match in the output (reset match start - similar to positive look-behind, but it works with variable-length matches)
- `.*?` - Non-greedy match stopping at the next match (this part will be output)
- `(?=<.*?>)` - Non-greedy match of any characters within angle brackets and don't include the match in the output (positive look-ahead - works with variable-length matches)

Comment: It will work only on Linux, as on OSX `-P` flag has been removed.

Comment: @kenorb: Note that GNU utilities are available for OS X. Using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use `html2text` command-line tool, which converts html into plain text.

Alternatively you may try [ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor))-way:

```
ex -s +'%s/<[^>].\{-}>//ge' +%p +q! file.txt
```

or:

```
cat file.txt | ex -s +'%s/<[^>].\{-}>//ge' +%p +q! /dev/stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a "perlgolf contest", but I used to use this trick.

Set Record Separator for `<` or `>`, then print only odd lines:

```
awk -vRS='<|>' NR%2 file.xml
```